# I have two images next to each other that I want to center and keep them centered in lower resolution

Tags: css

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Satch</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <img src="images/index_02.jpg" id="makeup" class="home">
        <img src="images/index_03.jpg" id="photography"class="home">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
img {
height: 100%;
float:left; 
}
body,html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

I want
- to center the two images horizontally
- to ensure that they don't go under each other in smaller resolution

please assist

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest thing I can come up with without more detail.

We tell the images to not take up more than 50% of their parent element's width width `max-width: 50%;`. For this solution, the images to not resize beyond their intrinsic width. We then center the images within the parent with `text-align: center;` as they are inline elements.

The reason for `font-size: 0;` is because of the line break between the two `<img>` tags creates white space for inline elements (think of them like text characters) and makes the contents of the container slightly more than 100% of the container's width when added up. As a result, smaller viewport sizes will reflow the second image to a new line. I like to think of the calculation like this:

`50% + white space + 50% = 100% + 1`

If you don't like `font-size: 0;` you could not have any space between the `<img>` in the markup, i.e. `<img><img>`.

```css
.img-container {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/fc0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/ccc">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `max-width: 50%;` to the images, see my example below.

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 img {
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="makeup" class="home">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="photography"class="home">
</div>
```

Comment: Images get squished at smaller resolutions.

Comment: @hungerstar that wasn't a requirement stated by the OP. It looks like they're more concerned with them being full height than being squished or not. If they need a solution where the images don't get squished, then we'd have to use background images or something.

Comment: Why did I get down-voted? Please tell me what's wrong!

Comment: You're right, the OP didn't explicitly make that a requirement. I was simply pointing out a very likely issue with the solution. As it stands we'll all have to make a few assumptions on what the OP intends the results to be. As far as full height, nothing in this solution is the full height of anything.

Comment: @hungerstar I see your point... The images and wrapper were the full height of the body, but it wasn't the full height of the browser—it is now.

Comment: Not trying to pick on you here, more of a teachable moment. The images and wrapper weren't the full height of the body either, it only appeared that way when you didn't have `html, body { height: 100%; }`. Previously the height of `body` was `0` as `#wrapper` contained floated elements that are taken out of the normal document flow and don't take up space. Since `#wrapper` didn't have a height due to floated child elements, therefore neither did `body`. When using percentage heights there needs to be a value that can be inherent from so **X%** can be calculated.

Comment: Eventually a length unit other than a percentage needs to be defined **or** percentage height declarations have to be made all the way up the DOM tree so it can inherit from the viewpoint. To see this happening simply inspect your Stack Snippet and remove `html, body {}`, then select `body` and `#wrapper` and you'll see that they have no height. Using percentage heights can be confusing (they confused me for awhile).

Comment: @hungerstar That makes sense—at least I think it does! I didn't realize that's how %s worked. I appreciate your time!

Comment: @hungerstar Your answer makes more sense to me than mine...When would you ever want to have an image that stretched proportionately? I'd vote for yours, but I don't have enough reputation yet. :-(

Comment: Did you mean, _"When would you ever want to have an image that stretched **unproportionately**?"_ In all my years of development I don't know if I've ever **wanted** an image to stretch/squish **non** proportionately. The only time I've allow some sort of _"modification"_ is when I've used `background-size: cover;` which will crop the edges of your image but maintain aspect ratio.